# Deploying .war file to tomcat 8 works fine in IDE but I lose all my JS and CSS when I deploy to my VPS

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application. When I start run it Tomcat 8.0_35 in my intellij IDE I have no issues, looks great. I decided to deploy in on my VPS and only the HTML renders. I replicated this issue on my localhost by manually dropping the .war file into webapps. Since I was getting all 404 errors I thought maybe I need to set up a webconfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/image/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/javascripts/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/javascripts/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/libs/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/lib/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(){
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();

        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

I needed the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` because I am using spring-mobile and I was having issues rendering my pages.

I am not seeing anything in the logs on tomcat either `localhost.log` and `cataline.log`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StidhamFinancialApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(StidhamFinancialApplication.class);

        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
       System.out.println(String.format("Access URLs:\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:%1s\n\t" +
                "External: \thttp://%2s:%3s\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("server.port"),
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
            env.getProperty("server.port")));
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(StidhamFinancialApplication.class);
    }
}
```

All my JS, and CSS file are found in my IDE and everything seems to be configured correctly. I am not sure what to try next. I have been debugging this for days with no luck.

I uploaded it on git at `https://github.com/drewjocham/financial`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Only thing the logs are complaining about is a few jar files:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan No TLD files were found in [file:/Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/stidhamfinancial/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
```

in my logging.properties I added the following:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=antlr-2.7.7.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=groovy-2.4.6.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip=aopalliance-1.0.jar
```

After doing some research but that doesn't seem to work. However I do not think this could be the issue.

Comment: Open up the generated .war file in your favorite zip tool. Are the files you are missing actually in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drew1208

I opened this Pull request that will solve your problem
https://github.com/drewjocham/financial/pull/1

I added some hibernate configs to be able to run and also execute the tests. And also removed the '/' from the resources path.

---

UPDATE

I found the issue.
The resources folder structure looks like that:
`resources
   css
     style.css
   images
     team-6-med-blur.png`

So in the file `style.css` the image path are relative to this file and not to the application context. Then you need to change from:
`background-image:url('resources/images/stidhamfinancial/team-6-med-blur.png');`
to
`background-image:url('../images/stidhamfinancial/team-6-med-blur.png');`

It will show the images.

Also I've opened this [PR#2](https://github.com/drewjocham/financial/pull/2) in your repo.

Comment: can we please chat? This only solved my issue with my desktop version. When I load mobile and table (spring-mobile does this) all the CSS images get 404 errors. I have changed them to `/resources/` to 'resources/` and got the same effect. Is there something different in spring mobile that I need to do.

Comment: Do you have time to chat?

Comment: If you look at the updated GIT project you will see the `/` are gone and it works when I deploy it to webapps but not for tablets and mobile via spring-mobile. In the CSS I needed the `/` for the index page but I tested it to see if I took off the `/` in the CSS and the mobile and tablets still did not work

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry. I've fixed just the index.html. I will take a look at tablet and mobile index.

Comment: If you look at my updated code it works but NOT when I manually deploy it to webapps. All the pictures I have in `styles.css` will not render. I tried to remove the `/` and leave it there. It is very strange. The main issue here is when I do `mvn clean install` take the war file and place it in `webapps` I am not getting the same behavior from when I run it on my IDE via Tomcat, strange.

Comment: I saw this exception in the tomcat log `2016-06-11 22:28:33.868 ERROR 33822 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/resources/css/resources/images/stidhamfinancial/team-6-med-blur.png] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false` it show me the error.

Comment: Yes I seen that too, however what is confusing is where is the added `/resources/` coming from? I was looking at my `@Configuration` file but nothing jumped out at me. Another thing that is odd is when it loads `it is normal` is render three times. The string comes from my controller via `spring-mobile`.

Comment: the additional `/resources/css` is the css file path. You can specify a relative path in your source code, but the browser needs and absolute path to request the resource.

Answer (score 6):

Always use relative paths for referencing the resource.

Snippet from your index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/superfish.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/nivo-slider.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/jquery.qtip.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
```

Should be

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/superfish.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/nivo-slider.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery.qtip.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery.fancybox.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
```

Explanation

When somebody uses "/" at the start of URL/resource, browser will try to load that resource from ROOT context of web server. A root context for web server may or may not be same as your application as application can be deployed at root context or any other context.

It is always advised to use relative paths to link your resource

You should use relative path for all static urls. I also found that many resources are not available in your github repo like superfish.css. Include those else they will result in 404

Comment: I did change it to the relative path then my picture were missing and I updated my project from GIT. I tried to revert it but even more files were missing. I reverted it back but I am missing a lot of file now. Thank goodness I have a backup on my other computer.

Comment: Please see the updated GIT. I had to go back and fix everything again. I had already done what you had mentioned however it was 2345 and I started to break things and tried to revert and made silly mistakes. If you have the time please have a look. I am still getting the same behavior, IDE works great but when I run `mvn clean install` and move the war file to webapps in Tomcat 8 only static HTML renders and 404 for everything else.

Comment: Yes that is correct however even when I do that and deploy it to my server I am missing some content still, you can see what I mean if you would like at `https://github.com/drewjocham/financial`.